# How to use jquery ajax with c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get my asp.net solution to work with jquery ajax. I am using this example:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

I have this so far, but it's giving me namespace errors about it not being defined. `Page` and `WebMethod` is not defined...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PDFLibrary.PDFLibrary
{
    public partial class SaveStructure : Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetDate()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't included the namespaces that would be required to use the `Page` and `WebMethod` classes.

Comment: Which ones are those?

Comment: `Page` is in `System.Web.UI`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.90).aspx  WebMethod is in System.Web.Services.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Is this available in .net 3.5?

Comment: `System.Web.UI` has been around since .NET 1.0

Comment: I put `using System.Web.Services;` but it not being found...

Comment: You need to reference the DLL in your project.

Comment: Do you have a web project?

Comment: Gotta learn how to read the MSDN documentation, sport.  There's a pulldown that allows you to change framework version, and it says which DLL the namespace is in, :)

Comment: If I browse for it when trying to add the reference in the popup box, I can find the system.web.services in the .net tab, but its .net 2. Is this ok?

Comment: @omega - Are you doing ASP.NET 2.0 or 3.5? Or ASP.NET 4.0/4.5? If ASP.NET 2.0/3.5, then choose the .NET 2.0 reference, otherwise the .NET 4.0 reference.

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 for Microsoft SharePoint 2010.

Comment: @Karl: How did you know that?  Is there something in the docs for us poor slobs who are not eloquent on the finer details of Microsoft versioning practices?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - here is a [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) There is no .NET Framework 3.0! Also, despite versioning the CLR as 4.5 for ASP.NET 4.5, it is actually using the CLR 4.0, it is 4.5 only in name, which I don't have that much of a problem with, it is the 3.5 stuff pointing to .NET 2.0 that is a confusing hot mess.

Comment: @Karl: Thanks, but it's not clear from that chart why ASP.NET 3.5 would still use a 2.0 DLL.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - The CLR version is what matters, until 4.5 which is incorrectly labeled as a new version despite it being an in-place update.

Comment: I should have used the term CLR from the beginning, instead of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio actually has a nice way of including missing namespaces.  Right click on `WebMethod` (or whatever is not recognized), mouse over the submenu that says `Resolve` and then select `using System.Whatever` which will be your missing namespace.

This is a nice feature that allows you to include namespaces without having to look them up.

Comment: You can also hot key this by clicking the offending term and clicking Ctrl + . (that is the control key and then the period symbol). I use it all the time. This will recommend any possible usings (Imports for VB.NET) that it can find in your project's References' DLLs. If you are not referencing the DLL, then it will of course not find it.

Comment: If the version I use is 2.0 (thats the one I found in the .net tab), I guess that should ok to use?

Comment: This would have been better as a comment.  It doesn't answer the question, but only continues the conversation below the question, so users coming to the site from Google are going to have a nice WTF moment.

Comment: His question: `Does anyone know how to fix this?`  Does my answer not solve this?

Comment: Alright, you got me there, I guess.  Is this sensitive to the target version that is set up in your VS project?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - absolutely, the target version of your project dictates which CLR you are bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] and [WebService(Namespace = "Your namespace(eg http://tempuri.org/)")]